# Shopify API: Get Orders In Shopify by Date

Tags: date, get, shopify, orders

Why fetching Orders from Shopify Store by date and limits always returns the orders of latest date?
Like: if I make a query for getting 5 orders from 1 august 2012
using this query:
`/admin/orders.json?status=open&created_at_min=2012-08-01 12:00&limit=5`

As I have 5 orders in 20 August 2012 and 5 orders in 31 August 2012
but this will returns 5 orders of latest date (31 August 2012).

Answer (score 5):

It's not documented, but you can do it by adding: `order=processed_at+asc` to your query.

Answer (score 3):

The Shopify API returns orders from Most Recent to Oldest.

When you submit your query Shopify will first create an array of your ten orders; the first five are from 31 August, the last 5 are from 20 August.

Then, by limiting it to five orders, Shopify gives you the first five.

As far as I'm aware, there is no way to specify your own sort order in the Shopify API. You'll need to get *all* the orders with `created_at_min= 2012-08-01` then, using whatever language you're writing in, get the last 5 items in the array.

Answer (score 1):

`&created_at_max=2012-08-01 11:59` does the trick

[shopify](http://www.shopify.com/?ref=softwarevamp) [order api](http://docs.shopify.com/api/order.html#index)

Answer (score 1):

Shopify API is specifically working on the EST/EDT time. So first convert your timezone time to EDT, So you can mark the exact time as per the EDT timezone.

Let's understand the example:
Currently, I'm in JST (TOKYO/ASIA) timezone, now I want the records for 2021-10-20 from order API as per the japan timings. So I need to make this kind of request parameter:

API:

```
orders.json?status=any&limit=250
```

Valid Parameter as per the date 2021-10-20 (JST)

1. If the requirement is for updated_at date

   `&updated_at_min=2021-10-19T11:00:00-04:00&updated_at_max=2021-10-20T11:00:00-04:00`
2. for created_at date

   `&created_at_min=2021-10-19T11:00:00-04:00&created_at_max=2021-10-20T11:00:00-04:00`

Here, We have actually converted the date of the JST (+09:00) format to EST(-04:00) for making sure that the data which I'm getting from the API should be only for 2021-10-20 date (From 2021-10-20 00:00:00 to 2021-10-21 00:00:00 [JST]).

Similarly, you can create the dates (EDT) format according to your timezone.

Answer (score 0):

According to my testing, converting ISO datetime format to UTC-4 works fine.

```
https://{{domain}}.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-04/orders.json?status=any&updated_at_min=2023-04-14T08:27:57-04:00&updated_at_max=2023-04-14T08:27:57-04:00
```

@Hitesh Kalwani's answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

As per the answers from [Hitesh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69642880/988246) and [XiaoLong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77339829/988246), you can use the `updated_at_min` and `updated_at_max` arguments to fetch orders placed within a certain range; and Shopify expects the times to be in EDT.

However, if you're not sure of your server's timezone, rather than trying to calculate it manually (with `-04:00` or `+02:00` or whatever), you can just set the default timezone for your script:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```

Then, to fetch all orders between now and a week ago, you can just use the `DateTime` constructor as normal without needing to calculate anything:

```
//  Get the date & time now:

$currentDateTime = new DateTime();
$currentDateTimeString = $currentDateTime->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s');

//  ...and the date & time 1 week ago
    
$interval = new DateInterval('P1W');    // P1W represents 1 week
$dateTimeWeekAgo = clone $currentDateTime;
$dateTimeWeekAgo->sub($interval);
$dateTimeWeekAgoString = $dateTimeWeekAgo->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s');

$ordersURL = 'https://{{domain}}.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-10/orders.json?status=any&updated_at_min=' . $dateTimeWeekAgoString . '&updated_at_max=' . $currentDateTimeString;
```

Answer (score -2):

for bettween two dates

```
/admin/orders.json?created_at_min=2012-08-01 12:00&limit=2012-08-01 12:00
```

Comment: only integer value can be allowed in limit attribute. As per the shopify document. https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2021-10/resources/order#[get]/admin/api/2021-10/orders.json