# Sort Order of Shopify REST Collections

Tags: rest, shopify

Trying to nail down what the sort order is for Shopify's REST collections.  Specifically I'm working with orders and customers at the moment.

I found this [closed thread](http://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/collections-sort-order-3670) discussing the ability to sort collections, and the API docs don't mention it at all for either [orders](http://api.shopify.com/order.html) or [customers](http://api.shopify.com/customer.html).

However, customers have a documented search API, which does have an order parameter as an option.  I'm not sure whether I can use it as a sort of substitute for the regular list API call.  This doesn't seem to work properly for example - it returns more than one result.

```
/admin/customers/search.json?query=&limit=1
```

Orders don't have a documented search endpoint, but I do get a response when hitting

```
/admin/orders/search.json?query=&limit=1
```

Although it has the same issues as the customer search endpoint.  I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318899/shopify-api-get-orders-in-shopify-by-date) saying that orders are always returned most recent to newest by date - and inspecting the response I'm getting now that *seems* to be true although I could have sworn I've seen them come back in a different orders, it almost seems indeterminate.

Would like to know if that's the case for sure, and the same for customers.  I seem to be getting them returned back in `created_at` order *ascending* for customers.  Is that always the case?

Also, ID's for both customers and orders don't seem to be in `created_at` order, which is bizzare given that the have the `since_id` parameter in pretty much all their collections (which I found and promptly built my incremental pulling strategy on top of).  I guess I'll have to use `created_at` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thread you linked to (apart from being really old) is referring to Collections (with a capital C), which are how groups of products are defined in Shopify (e.g. Shoes, Coats, Hats, etc.).

The 'collections' you're referring to (Customers, Products, Orders, etc.) are returned in descending date order (i.e. newest first) if the `since_id` parameter is not supplied, and in ascending order if it is supplied. Note that this *should* correspond with a descending id ordering, that's the idea at any rate as it allows you to use `since_id` to paginate properly (as you're doing).

Double check that you're getting wonky id ordering and if you are, please post the store domain you're seeing it on as well as a sample of order ids so that we can look into it.

Comment: Thanks David.  So it seems to return the results in ascending order when `since_id` is supplied, and descending order otherwise.  My domain is kohler-jerde2431.myshopify.com

Comment: Can you confirm that that's expected?

Comment: You're correct. Specifying `since_id` flips the sort order so you'll get the first `x` results after the specified id where `x` is the `limit` param you pass with the call.

Comment: Do they come in ascending order if *any* filter is applied?  I needed to change my query from using `since_id` to using `updated_at_min`.  It *does appear* to come in ascending order, just want to confirm.

Comment: I had a similar problem when retrieving order data - for `since_id`, I got an unspecified sorting (neither ascending nor descending, but mixed for both `created_at`, `updated_at`, and id values). I ended up using `created_at_max` (which seems to return newest orders first) and paging.

Comment: Hey @DavidUnderwood, did the API change the way that it sorts collections?  I'm getting order results back in descending order even when an `updated_at_min` is supplied, whereas previously they were coming in ascending.  If I use `updated_at_max`, then they come in ascending order.

Comment: @LarsGrammel, nice find.  But for doing ongoing syncs, don't we need to be querying on `updated_at`, not `created_at`?  It worked out a lot better when I could use `updated_at_min` and get results in ascending order.

Comment: @DavidUnderwood here's a dpaste including the domain name and payload: http://dpaste.com/1039139/

Comment: @DavidUnderwood Since the answer was already accepted without `updated_at` being specified, I went ahead and opened up another question for it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15766479/how-are-shopify-api-order-collections-sorted-when-passing-in-an-updated-at-filte